# I'm trying to ascertain how is my Networkmanager receives specific name server information- possibly Cobbler related

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, resolv.conf, cobbler, networkmanager

When I:

```
cat /etc/resolve.conf
```

I see:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 10.100.48.19
nameserver 10.100.48.17
```

When I change this info then reboot, the original information returns. 
I'm trying to work out where these specific addresses are stored so I can reconfigure them, so that when my client machines are re-started they contain the new DNS details. 
The network has a Cobbler service running which provides DHCP. I believe this may be where the resolve.conf info is sourced (although I'm not 100% on that). I can't find anywhere on cobbler where global DNS settings are potentially stored for DHCP clients. Can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you change that file on the clients, it will be re-generated by NetworkManager. The same would be true of any network that sends DNS nameserver information along with addresses via DHCP, not just cobbler.

Editing the DHCP configuration of cobbler is pretty easy, but you must first identify which DHCP server you're using as a cobbler module. That information is stored in /etc/cobbler/modules.conf. There you will find either the ISC-DHCP server module set for DHCP, or the dnsmasq module set in its stead. Focus on the DHCP module, not the DNS one.

Editing the isc-dhcp-server configuration is easily done via the /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf file. Within your subnet declaration, you will find the option for DNS nameservers as doled out by DHCP for that subnet. Change this there. don't forget to restart or config reload the isc-dhcp-server to use the new configuration.

Dnsmasq can be changed similarly, via the file /etc/dnsmasq.conf (or similar, as it varies more from distribution to distribution). On the DNS= line, make your edit there. As before, reload the dnsmasq service.